# Как завершить спящие процессы ничего не сломав?

Tags: sql-server

Программа создаёт блокировки и процессы которые висят. Помогает завершение процессов с помощью T-SQL. Но есть проблема, вместе с этим завершаются нужные процессы, в следствии чего набранные данные не сохраняются(было замечено несколько раз) или при работе в другом окне программы завершается процесс главной формы.

```
DECLARE @v_spid INT
DECLARE c_Users CURSOR
   FAST_FORWARD FOR
   SELECT SPID
   FROM master..sysprocesses (NOLOCK)
   WHERE spid>50 
   AND status='sleeping' 
   AND DATEDIFF(mi,last_batch,GETDATE())>=5
   AND spid<>@@spid

OPEN c_Users
FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN
  PRINT 'KILLing '+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@v_spid)+'...'
  EXEC('KILL '+@v_spid)
  FETCH NEXT FROM c_Users INTO @v_spid
END

CLOSE c_Users
DEALLOCATE c_Users
```

Comment: Если исходники программы доступны расставить в ней commit сразу после совершения операций в БД. Это единственный путь борьбы с блокировками. Ни одно приложение _не имеет права_ ожидать действий пользователя или заниматься другой работой не связанной с БД не завершив транзакции. А завершение процессов это лечение насморка отсечением головы

Comment: @Mike После SELECT мы должны сделать COMMIT? Потому что я видел процессы из-за которых всё висело и это были SELECT. Может БД ещё не успела записать данные в базу? Там же есть какой-то тайм-аут перед записью в файл БД.

Comment: select не делает блокировок, если ему явно не сказано их делать (for update или спец. ключи типа lock). Если висят select, то возможно они ждут пока какое то обновление завершит работу и снимет блокировки. Обновление же БД окончательно пишется в БД и снимает все блокировки как только дан commit. Наиболее частая проблема в приложениях, приводящая к массовому подвисанию процессов, что после операции обновления забывают дать commit и приложение с незавершенной транзакцией ожидает пользовательского ввода (а он кофе пошел пить). когда вы такой процесс прибьете, то конечно инфа будет потеряна

Comment: так что для начала посмотрите какие именно блокировки долго не пропадают. смотрите на какие они таблицы, ищите место в приложении которое пишет эти таблицы и смотрите его на предмет commit'ов

Comment: @Mike Вы не могли бы более подробно описать процесс поиска причины блокировок? Дать инструкцию с примером?

Comment: в гугле наберите "ms sql список блокировок". Я могу только переписывать инфу от туда же, ибо сам плотно с MS SQL не работал. давно сталкивался с sybase, до того момента когда они продали исходники MS и те из них сделали sql-server

Comment: @Mike Можно ли мне помочь другим способом не переписывая программу? Может постоянно выполнять какой-нибудь код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нехорошо убивать процессы, не выяснив причину. Тем более, что *sleeping* означает ожидание сервером запроса от клиента, а под это условие могут быть квалифицированы сессии в совершенно разном логическом состоянии.

У сессии может быть открытая транзакция и она может быть в состоянии *sleeping* между отдельными командами, а может не быть открытых транзакций - например, клиент просто подсоединился к серверу, или клиент подсоединился и сделал запрос, а соединение не закрыл (скоро опять понадобится).

> процессы которые висят

Вам лучше расследовать ситуацию. Иногда бывает достаточно *sp_who*, *sp_who2* и *sp_lock*.

Основные причины подвисания процесса при запросе, как правило:

1. запрос никто не блокирует, он долгий сам по себе
2. запрос долгий, потому что он блокируется чем-то

   - другим запросом
   - пользовательской транзакцией

Поищите сессии, делающие долгие запросы

```
SELECT
    s.session_id,
    r.total_elapsed_time,
    r.wait_time,
    r.wait_type,
    r.wait_resource,
    r.blocking_session_id
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_sessions s
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON r.session_id = s.session_id
WHERE
    s.is_user_process = 1 AND s.session_id != @@SPID
ORDER BY
    r.total_elapsed_time DESC;
```

Если сессия блокирована кем-то, то вы увидите идентификатор сессии в `blocking_session_id`.

Потом уже по конкретной сессии можно посмотреть что в ней происходит вплоть до текста и плана конкретно выполняющейся в данный момент команды:

```
SELECT
    r.session_id,
    t.text,
    p.query_plan,
    stmt_text =
        SUBSTRING(
            t.text,
            r.statement_start_offset / 2 + 1,
            (CASE r.statement_end_offset WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(t.text) ELSE r.statement_end_offset END - r.statement_start_offset) / 2 + 1
        ),
    stmt_plan = CAST(stp.query_plan AS xml)
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(r.plan_handle) p
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.plan_handle) t
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_text_query_plan(r.plan_handle, r.statement_start_offset, r.statement_end_offset) stp
WHERE
    r.session_id = @sessionID;
```

Поискать сессии с незавершенными транзакциями можно, например, так:

```
SELECT
    s_tr.session_id,
    a_tr.transaction_id,
    open_time_msec = DATEDIFF(millisecond, a_tr.transaction_begin_time, GETDATE())
FROM
    sys.dm_tran_session_transactions s_tr
    JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions a_tr ON a_tr.transaction_id = s_tr.transaction_id
WHERE
    s_tr.is_user_transaction = 1 AND s_tr.session_id != @@SPID
ORDER BY
    a_tr.transaction_begin_time;
```

Comment: У меня стоит SQL 2000 SP 4